How to keep the first appearance of a value while filtering everything else out in R?
This is the appearance of my dataset currently. I want to include patient 1 data until the first '1' occurs in 'test.result' then remove any information about patient 1 after that.
current dataset
This is what I have tried so far- it removed all the 0 values in my data but didn't delete all the other 1 values for each patient after the first initial 1.
I want to keep the 0 values for a patient if they are not preceeded by a 1.
new.ddset <- ddset %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(test.result == max(test.result))

This is what I want in my results:
EX: For id1, at screen.num 1-5, the test.result was 0, but at screen 6, screen.num was 1 - I want to keep all the information for that id up to screen 6 and delete all other id information for id1 after that.

Try the following.
filter(df, cumsum(test.result)<=1  
       & test.result==cummax(test.result), .by=ID)


  ID seq test.result
1  1   1           1
2  2   1           0
3  2   2           1
4  3   1           0
5  3   2           0
6  3   3           0
7  3   4           1


Data
df
   ID seq test.result
1   1   1           1
2   1   2           0
3   1   3           1
4   1   4           0
5   1   5           0
6   2   1           0
7   2   2           1
8   2   3           0
9   2   4           0
10  3   1           0
11  3   2           0
12  3   3           0
13  3   4           1

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    seq = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), test.result = c(1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))


We might use tapply to generate a Boolean vector:
df[unlist(tapply(df, ~ID, \(x) with(x, test.result<=1L & test.result==cumsum(test.result)))), ]
#>    ID seq test.result
#> 1   1   1           1
#> 6   2   1           0
#> 7   2   2           1
#> 10  3   1           0
#> 11  3   2           0
#> 12  3   3           0
#> 13  3   4           1

